# Как в меню nw.js прикрутить иконки

Tags: javascript, меню

Создаю программу на nw.js. Никак не могу понять как в главном меню сделать меню с иконками, и есть ли возможность увеличить размер шрифта. Пробовал делать по аналогии с меню в трее, но ничего не выходит.

Comment: можешь по конкретнее ничего не пронятно